# Add New Column EmojiName in the existing DataFrame in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, emoji

df_1 is a dataframe having a column called 'message'. This column has few emojis as well.
I am trying to create a new dataframe df_2 with Emoji and EmojiName.

Below code gives me Icon of the Emoji:

```
import emoji
emojis =[]
for message in df_1['message']:
    emojis.extend(c for c in message if c in emoji.EMOJI_DATA)
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(emojis)
```

Now in the same datframe df_2, I would like to add one more column called "EmojiName"
I know that there is a function called "emoji.EMOJI_DATA" which gives you description of the emoji but I am not able to use that to create a dataframe column.

Require your help.

Comment: This approach only supports simple (single codepoint) emojis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a mapping Series:

```
emoji_names = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(emoji.EMOJI_DATA, orient='index')['en']
# or
emoji_names = {k: d['en'] for k,d in emoji.EMOJI_DATA.items()}

df_2['EmojiName'] = df_2[0].map(emoji_names)
```

Example output:

```
   0    EmojiName
0    :thumbs_up:
1  ❤  :red_heart:
```

Used input:

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'message': ['Python is ', 'I ❤️ python']})
```